# What causes a segfault in C++ STL list node memory allocation?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, porting, allocation

I've written some C++ code that runs perfectly fine on my laptop PC (compiled under both a Microsoft compiler and g++ under MinGW). I am in the process of porting it to a Unix machine.

I've compiled with both g++ and with Intel's ipcp on the Unix machine and in both cases, my program crashes (segfaults) after running for a while. I can run it for a short time without a crash.

When I debug, I find that the crash is happening when the program tries to copy an STL list - specifically, it happens when the program tries to allocate memory to create a new node in the list. And the error I get in the debugger (TotalView) is that "an allocation call failed or the address returned is null."

The crash does not always happen in the same place in the code each time I run it, but does always happen during an allocation call to create a node in an STL list. I don't think I'm running out of memory. I have a few memory leaks, but they're very small. What else can cause a memory allocation error? And why does it happen on the Unix machine and not on my PC?

UPDATE: I used MemoryScape to help debug. When I used guard blocks, the program ran through without crashing, further suggesting a memory issue. What finally worked to nail down the problem was to "paint" allocated memory. It turns out I was initializing a variable, but not setting it to a value before I used it as an array index. The array was therefore overrunning because it was using whatever garbage was in the variable's memory location -- often it was 0 or some other small number, so no problem. But when I ran the program long enough, it was more likely to hold a larger number and corrupt the heap when I wrote out of bounds of the array. Painting the allocated memory with a large number forced a segfault right at the line of code where I attempted to write a value in the array and I could see that large painted number being used as the array index.

Comment: There are so many possible causes of segfaults, it is not only impossible to post them all here, it also makes no sense as it would not lead anywhere. If otoh you would post some nice testcase, we could tell more.

Comment: Since you're on Unix, take the oportunity to have a run with Valgrind, it's quite helpful with memory issues.

Comment: It would be helpfull to see a the code snipet. But if you are getting memmory allocation problems, one of the first things to check is if your program is leaking. Have you looked at the memory consumption of your process?

Comment: For the time being, you can verify if the crash is caused by `std::bad_alloc` propagating out of main.

Comment: Need to see code. But this usually means you are writing over the end some memory structure. Turn up the warning level of your compiler and make sure there are 0 warnings (this may help).

Comment: Thanks everyone, but I don't think a code snippet is going to help -- it's a very large program and if I knew where the problem was I'd be able to debug it. The code crashes in different places, but never on the first time through. For example, it sometimes crashes here: if (!(*iter2)->IsInList(already))  where "already" is an STL list and the code specifically crashes when it attempts to to copy the list "already" in order to send it to method IsInList(). I'm going to have a go with a memory tool as suggested and see if I can figure out more... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a corruption of the dynamic memory allocation data structures, which is often caused by other, unrelated code. This type of bug is notorious for being hard to find and reproduce without external tools, because any change in memory layout can mask it. It probably worked through luck in the Windows version.

Memory debuggers are great tools to catch such corruption. `valgrind`, `dmalloc` and `efence` are very good alternatives to check the correctness of your program.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely caused by heap corruption - elsewhere in the code, you're overwriting freed memory, or writing to memory outside the bounds of your memory allocations (buffer overflows, or writing before the start of allocated memory). Heap corruption typically results in crashes at an unrelated location, such as in STL code. Since you're on a unix platform, you should try running your program under valgrind to try to identify the original heap corruption.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I have a few memory leaks, but they're very small.
```

Well, if you run it for a while, then it ends up being a lot of memory. That's kind of the thing about leaks. You should log your memory usage at the point of the crash to see if there was any memory available.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I mentioned they were small, because I have run the program all the way through, and the total memory consumed is just a few K. A memory tool shows that there's still memory available, so I don't think I'm running out of memory.

Comment: It only ends up being a lot of memory if the suspect code is executed within a loop.  If it leaks 8 bytes at startup and the code is never called again, the program will only leak 8 bytes no matter how long it runs.